# Passing picturebox image into PDF file

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm trying to pass image to PDF file, but what it does it takes image `Size Mode` (**in PDF** file while showing me **on form** as a stretchimage) as Normal even if I set it to stretchimage. Here is My code:

```
private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    SaveFileDialog svg = new SaveFileDialog();
    svg.ShowDialog();

    Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
    PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(svg.FileName + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
    doc.Open();

    iTextSharp.text.Image png = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(pictureBox1.Image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    doc.Add(png);

    doc.Close();
}
```